# Can you find my friends' birthday

Tags: logical-deduction, word-problem

A friend of mine has an interesting birthday.

If you shorten the date month and year and use UK date format, it reads the year in full, his birthday falls on a Friday.

When he is as old as the year of his birth (last two digits of the year), his birthday will also be a Friday, lets call this the Magic day.

He observed that there could be many dates similar to his birthday, however he noted that for one such date in the past, his birthday is the Magic day.

Can you find my friends' birthday if he is still alive?

Comment: You might want to clarify what "UK date format" is for those who don't live in the UK.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate but I can't find it. I remember it though!

Comment: Oh come on, this is made up by me... can never be a duplicate

Comment: possible duplicate of [Odd birthdate surprise](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2335/odd-birthdate-surprise)

Comment: If you think this question is a duplicate of that... may lord bless you

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question then.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work --You can change Accepted Answer if another is of better quality, don't do it just because if speed.

Comment: If you can find another date that will fit all of these rules I will accept yours @warspyking there is one other date, which I have indicated as invalid just by one word in the question

Comment: @skv Which word? Besides, I cannot let you accept my answer if it's invalid.

Comment: Try to find :) the date that fits first then you will understand the word

Comment: @skv Found it, still don't get the word, see my answer! :D

Comment: The word is "will also be a Friday" in the question indicates that this Magic day is actually in the future

Comment: @warspyking While not quite a duplicate, that question is definitely relevant. Specifically, it gives us the name "Beddian Birthday" that is slightly more satisfying than "Magic Day".

Comment: Also, let me verify the conditions: 1, when written like "day/month/year" the birthday is the same as the year. 2, his birthday was a Friday. 3, his Beddian Birthday is also on a Friday. If this is correct, would you mind making that clearer? I had to read the comments and answers to understand the question. I have no idea what the paragraph starting "He observed..." means to say.

Comment: Actually, I've just noticed that the "Magic Day" isn't quite the Beddian Birthday. The rest still stands, though.

Comment: So which point do you feel needs additional clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got this right the "magic day" would be the day/month/year that his birthday falls on, in which his age matches up with the last 2 dates of the year he was born?

Well, here's one possible solution. The birth date fell on:

> 1/9/39

The birthday ("magic day") was:

> 1/9/78

If the above is his DOB then **HIS** magic day would be:

> 1/9/2056

Otherwise, we'd need to know his age.

Logic:

> Obviously the day and month had to be the same in both dates. We should try 1/9 first, it's the most logical assumption as it's closest to us.  Meaning it's September the 1<sup>st</sup>. Going through the trial and error method, we eventually find 1/9/39. We then check 1/9/78 because obviously the year has to be doubled for the person's age to match the last 2 digits. Low and behold, it's on a Friday. Then of course to find his magic day we go ahead of 1978 by, obviously, 78, to get 2056!

He is in fact still alive.

It took me a while to answer this, because it seemed to me as if the question wanted the DOB and the magic day, I didn't get the part about HIS magic day and the other person's magic day being his DOB.

Alternative Solution:

> If you go back farther than 1939 you can also find DOB: 1911 and Magic Day: 1922 making his birthday/magic day: 1944

But this won't fit the question as the question states his birthday on his magic day "will be" indicating that this Magic day is in future

Comment: I think the understanding is correct, but the question is not what you have answered

Comment: How did I not answer the question? I provided both his date of birth, and his birthday (the "magic day"). In fact I didn't even need to give you his DOB as all you ask for is the birthday, and I quite "Can you find my friends' birthday if he is still alive"

Comment: @skv Well? How didn't I?

Comment: I think there is a slight misunderstanding, magic day is supposed to be the birthday that you will celebrate when you are as old as the last two digits of your year of birth.  You have identified the facts, but if you modify the answer accordingly I shall accept

Comment: @skv I have given you the magic day, and I gave the DOB, and I explained how I got it. What other information could I possibly be missing?

Comment: :) "He observed that there could be many dates similar to his birthday, however he noted that for one such date in the past, his birthday is the Magic day" so his birthday is someone else's magic day :) you have not yet found my friends' magic day... does that answer your question... also if you consider this, you would understand that the order of your answer is slightly incorrect

Comment: I still don't get it... Could you reword the question?

Comment: Define what exactly "magic day" is supposed to mean.

Comment: "When he is as old as the year of his birth(last two digits of the year), his birthday will also be a Friday, lets call this the Magic day" this is HIS magic day, so if you date of birth is 01/01/1990 then your magic day is 01/01/2180

Comment: Don't you mean 01/01/2080? Anyway, if his DOB is 1/9/39 his magic day is 1/9/78 right? So if they both fall on Fridays wouldn't this be correct? I fail to see what I've done incorrectly. It matches the question criteria. If it's another date that works the same way, I could theoretically be here all day looking for it...

Comment: @skv I'm obviously being oblivious to something....

Comment: Yes, his birthday is someone else's magic day, so what is his birthday

Comment: @skv I think I get what you mean now...

Comment: @skv updated answer. I explain it fully so others can understand it too! I hope you accept this.

Answer (score 1):

> September 1st 1978

His Magic day:

> September 1st 2056

His birthday is magic day for

> September 1st 1939

**Explaination**

> UK date representation is `DDMMYYYY`, puzzle shortened it so it would be `DMYY`. Friend could not be younger than 16 since `2/0` doesn't account for any date, so `D/M` has to be `1/9`, hence first of Sept.
> Testing years going back, this date was on Friday on `95` & `89` but Since Magic day is adding a number to itself, it can't be on a odd numbered year. Next one back is `78`, where `2056` has the Magic day, and dividing the number by 2 to `1939` shows us that the date `1/9/78` is indeed Magic day for `1/9/39`.
> `1950` could have worked, but `1/9/25` was not a Friday. No other `19xx` date would be relevant, since before `1950` Magic day would come out in `19xx's`, but we eliminated those (Besides `78`, which is our answer).
> Going back to `18xx` years would [be against](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Life_Expectancy_at_Birth_by_Region_1950-2050.png) the "Friend being alive" rule...

Comment: You didn't explain how you got your answer, so you may not get to keep the accepted answer. You do not pick which is accepted due to speed, you pick due to quality! :D

Comment: @warspyking, like it now?

Comment: Not exactly, I like the explanation but "Can you find my friends' birthday if he is still alive" is not a rule, it seems to imply it wants you to state if the person is dead though.

Comment: There is one more entire set which meets all my rules (Except one subtle rule in the question) can you find that out if you are curious